# Using a net while mounted to drag someone around

Tags: pathfinder-1e, mounted-combat

Are there any rules on dragging someone around via a [net](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/net) while mounted?

If there are none, would you allow it, and what rules would you use for it?

Comment: I don't see any rules for dragging someone around via a net even while **not** mounted. Am I missing something? The way we houseruled such situations was opposed STR check (just like with holding the tether), with bonuses or penalties depending on the surface. Horse's strength if saddle was equipped with saddle horn, like western saddles. But it was about dragging someone on lasso, not net, and we didn't bothered with RAW too much then anyway.

Comment: Dragging someone while mounted is bound to make a little more damage than on foot, I assume ?

Comment: @Nigralbus have you found *any* rules about dragging someone at all?

Comment: Can whomever down voted the question please let me know why? I couldn't find any rules when I looked for them, so this seems a perfectly valid question to me?

Comment: I am very certain I saw rules for "dragging" under some monster rules. It basically acted like a reverse bull-rush (in that they were pulled closer instead of pushed away), but I can't seem to find it in the core rulebook. In any case, even then, it would need adjustments for the mounted combat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found any rules on it, but I would treat it very much like a grapple check, but with you making automatic attacks, that are guaranteed to hit if the player moves.

The initial roll would have to be made with your DEX modifier, since you are trying to entangle him with a thrown net. Every check after that would be made with your CMB, since it's just you keeping him in there, which requires more strength then dexterity.

Terrain and speed will also effect how easy it is to hold him. Dragging over something like cobblestone or grass is easy (but would deal different damage). But dragging through the underbrush would be tough, since it will get caught, so you would get a -3 penalty for that turn's check. Jumping over a log or boulder would give you a -1 to your check.

For every 20ft you drag in one turn, deal 1d(something) +1 of damage. So if you move 30 ft, then 30ft, each turn would still only deal 1d +1 of damage.

Finally, the terrain would deal different damage:

- Grass: 1d2 Dirt/Stone
- Floor: 1d3
- Cobblestone/loose rocks:1d4
- Underbrush: 1d6
- Soft obstacle: 1d8
- Hard obstacle 1d10

In addition, fire would deal +1d3 of fire damage for 1d3 turns, after which, the net will have burned (unless it's a special fireproof net)

---

Ride check would also be very important, and every turn you would need to make a ride check depending on who you are dragging. If you lose them, you will need to make a ride check DC20 or be knocked off your mount.

Answer (score 3):

As in mawimawi and Flotolk's answers, I'm not sure there are any clear rules here, but there are lots of things that we could easily make up. But there are several variable to consider that might hinder this one way or the other.

First off, you cannot use a normal net, you must use a [Snag Net](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/net-snag). The normal net is thrown at the opponent but does not have a rope you can use to pull / trip / drag them.

How would this work?

1. Make an attack with the Snag Net as usual. Obviously you need this to succeed or nothing else works.
2. Once they are trapped you are going to perform the Drag maneuver. Drag even details how far you can Drag the opponent.
3. That does not knock the opponent prone. If you want them on the ground you need to make an Overrun (*win by 5*) or a Trip maneuver (*described in snag net*).

See [here for a list of the maneuvers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Combat-Maneuvers) with extra details.

This would actually describe a simple Drag without use of the horse. So the DM's role here is really to figure out how the horse impacts this.

*If I were a DM*... Here's what I would do:

1. I would allow you to make the Drag with the Horse's STR modifier added to your CMB.
2. I would double the allowed movement if the creature was prone.
3. The Dragged creature would not suffer any damage unless they were prone.
4. I would allow the Dragged creature a Disarm maneuver to "pull away" the rope from the player holding it. This would be on top of the normal Escape Artist or Strength check to clear the net.

Answer (score 2):

There are no official rules for that, but as a GM, I definitely would allow it, since it makes up for a great story. First of all - as Molot described - there would be a continuous STR check if the net is held in hand. If the net is fixated on a saddle, then I might use a low ride check instead.

I would take into account the speed of your mount per round as well as the terrain from grass (d2-1) to cobblestone (d4) to rocky (d8+1). For every 20 ft I'd add a dice. So if it's on a cobblestone street, and you drag the victim for 60 ft, I'd roll 3d4.

If there's a nasty obstacle like a trunk lying in the path where the mount jumps over, but the victim can't pass safely I'd use additional damage like 1d10+5 to really hurt him.

In my opinion, it's just GM fiat, and I would try to describe everything in excruciating detail.

Comment: Good point with low ride check, but only if enemy is substantially lighter and weaker than horse. Light Riding Horse is Str 16, Heavy Str 20. So first level character can be possibly just as strong, or even stronger! Why couldn't he drag horse instead?

Comment: For a really strong and heavy creature it makes sense to not let the mount run as fast as usual. But I don't think a STR check would be needed, since the victim can not stand correctly - in my opinion he isn't just "entangled" but "helpless" as soon as the mount starts to move.

Comment: Victim can stand, is only entangled: –2 penalty on attack rolls and a –4 penalty on Dexterity, can move at only half speed, and cannot charge or run. Nothing else. More, opposed Str check is already described in net rules, when victim tries to move and attacker tries to stay in place. No bonuses nor penalties for either side. Why wouldn't it be the same if the other party is pulling, really?

Comment: Hm, that really makes sense, yes. But as soon as the mount starts moving, the entangled creature will be unable to stay on its feet, so from that moment on, I'd consider the victim helpless.

Comment: When creature is in drag, true. But to start dragging... and decide who drags who? This part is oversimplified in your answer and may really hurt if that's PC who is dragged. Especially if player built his PC with "strong as a horse" in mind.

Comment: The horse has four legs and its mass as advantages (the grappling rules include some of that), so that should/would be considered in the DM fiat process. Strength is useless without leverage, and the horse has the advantage in leverage against someone in a net.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question. I would argue while the rules don't explicitly cover this, you could find some guidance in the rules. It would benefit you to look at some real-world examples. The one that comes to my mind is roping.

1. The rider makes an attempt to 'rope' or 'hit' the animal with the rope, catching a leg
2. The rider attempts to secure the rope on the saddle (very dangerous; I have a 3 fingered brother-in-law who could attest)
3. The rider attempts to control the animal while an ally secures the animal.

If the rider attempted to drag the animal (usually a calf), he would risk hurting the horse (I've also seen a horse's back broken from a fall). This would be much simpler with a human defender, but difficult terrain or other obstacle that caused the defender to get hung up would be almost as dangerous for the horse and rider. If the rider did not secure the net to the saddle, he would get un-horsed by anything that hung up the dragged opponent.

So what does this mean in game terms?

1. Attack roll (as normal) to hit the target with the net.
2. Rope check (or something similar) to secure the rope to the saddle.
3. If the rider decides to attempt a drag, something like a STR check between the horse and the target or rider (if rope was not secured) and target.
4. Reflex save for target to avoid going prone (or opposed ride/dex) though this would also be impacted by the speed differential (you can't maintain your feet if you can't keep up)
5. Reflex save for the target to lessen damage (maybe convert some to non-lethal)
   or if the rider is just attempting to control the target
6. Escape artist check for target (as normal for net, perhaps with added modifiers)

You could look to environmental damage to work out the effects (like slide damage or fall damage) to guide you. (Like a successful reflex save converts some damage to non-lethal, distance horizontally might equate to 1/2 or 1/4 distance vertically - so maybe a 60' drag does 3d6 damage, half is non-lethal if successful reflex save, increase damage for difficult terrain). I would also include some threat to the attacker, since while getting hung up will hurt the defender, it could potentially hurt the rider (and horse) as well.